# Jenkins - how to make groups for nodes in build executor list?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-plugins

My team has a lot of nodes connected to our Jenkins instance. Over 50 at the moment. Which creates a long vertical list of every node when looking at the Jenkins UI, under "BUILD EXECUTOR STATUS" on the left of the home screen.

Is there anyway to group these nodes together to make that list less ridiculous?

The list I'm talking about is here:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/idjtB.png

I'd like to make custom drop down folders like WINDOWS, APPLE, LINUX and have all the related nodes be in those lists instead of showing everything in one long list.

Is this possible? Or is making a custom view still my only option?

Answer (score 0):

I have also been searching for a ready-made solution for this.

I managed to reduce the "BUILD EXECUTOR STATUS" list by configuring agent availability and using the "Build Executors Filter Offline" plugin. Jenkins disable agents when they are not needed, and the "Build Executors Filter Offline" plugin hides the disabled agents from the list.
Please note that this approach adds a 1-minute delay when starting a job. Initially, Jenkins queues the job, and only after a minute does it attempt to connect to the agent and start executing the job.